# forEach filter. to render database by id

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'd like to render a meal by ID and also shows reviews for that meal.
I could render a review but it is always the same ID.
So when user clicks on a menu which is ID:2, then reviews for menu ID:2 should be shown together.

Meals and reviews are stored in MySQL.
in review table, there are columns:
id, numberOfStars, content, meal_id, createdAt

meal_id in review table is related to id in meal table.

I think forEach and filter methods are not correct.
Would be appreciated if I could get help.

I have my code:

```
window.handleMealRequest = async(params)=> {
  const getMealResponse = await fetch(`/api/meals/${params.id}`);
  const meals = await getMealResponse.json();
  const mealById = meals[0];

  const getReview = await fetch(`/api/reviews`);
  const reviewToRender = await getReview.json();
  const reviewById = reviewToRender[0];
  fetch(`/api/meals/${params.id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(meal => {
      meal.forEach(m => {
        m.getReview = reviewToRender.filter(reviewToRender => meal.id === reviewToRender.meal_id);
        return m;
      })
    })
  document.body.innerHTML =
     `
        <-- HERE I HAVE MEAL MENU TO RENDER AND I'D LIKE TO SHOW REVIEWS FOR THE MEAL DOWN BELOW -->

        <div>
          <p>Review created at: ${reviewById.createdAt}</p>
          <p>Stars: ${reviewById.numberOfStars}</p>
          ${reviewById.content}
        </div>
     `;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're always rendering the first review. (look at line `const reviewById = reviewToRender[0];`). I believe what you meant to do is find the review which corresponds to the selected meal:

```
const reviewById = reviewToRender.find(r => +r.meal_id == +meal.id)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I have a question. What is '+' in front of meal_id and meal.id ?

Comment: it converts a string to number

Answer (score 0):

Method `forEach` doesn't do anything, just goes through the array, but `map` returns modified array

```
const meals = await fetch(`/api/meals/${params.id}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(meal => {
  meal.map(m => {
    m.getReview = reviewToRender.find(reviewToRender => meal.id ===    reviewToRender.meal_id);
    return m;
  })
})
```

After you'll have an array `meals` whose elements contain the field `getReview`

Comment: thank you for your help. When I log out 'm' (instead of return), m logged out a meal not reviews. As Omar mentioned, I'd like to find the review which corresponds to the selected meal. Would you have an idea how to do?

Comment: now u have a meal_id `reviewToRender.filter(r => r.meal_id === meal_id)` Edit: `filter` returns an array

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few points amiss with your approach. It will be difficult to actually provide some error-free code here as we don't have a working snippet but I will try nonetheless:

```
const fj=arg=>fetch(arg).then(r=>r.json());         // helper function for brevity
window.handleMealRequest = async(params)=> {
  const meal = await fj(`/api/meals/${params.id}`); // data for ONE meal
  const reviews = await fj(`/api/reviews`);         // data for ALL reviews here
  // your second "fetch(`/api/meals/${params.id}`)" would be totally redundant here!
  const meal.reviews = reviews.filter(r => +r.meal_id == +meal.id)  // filter out reviews
  // now you should have the object meal with a property reviews in it, which is an array
  // containing all reviews pertaining to the meal with meal.id==params.id
  document.body.innerHTML = ... // Do the document rendering here, within the 
  ...                           // async function body.
  ..
  .
}
```